# Hive-Hbase Integration issue -org/apache/hadoop/hive/hbase/HiveHBaseTableInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

I am trying to intgrate hive with Hbase.    I am using pivotal VM

```
add jar /usr/lib/gphd/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.12.0-gphd-3.0.0.0.jar
add jar /usr/lib/gphd/hive/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar;
add jar /usr/lib/gphd/hbase/lib/hbase-common.jar;
add jar /usr/lib/gphd/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar;
add jar /usr/lib/gphd/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;
```

My hive query is below:

```
create TABLE hbase_table
(age int, name string,id string,sal string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal data:age,personal data:name,professional data:id,,professional data:sal") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "employee");
```

But it gives the error:

```
 Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/hbase/HiveHBaseTableInputFormat
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH** environment variable to `/usr/lib/gphd/hbase/lib/` in  `/etc/hive/conf/hive-env.sh`

This should resolve the issue.